# Active Record Setup Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

this is what I have so far:

A Content class that belongs to the User class:

```
class Content < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here is what my User class looks like:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :contents
end
```

And here is what my schema.rb looks like:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150723165743) do

  create_table "contents", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "content"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string  "username"
    t.string  "password"
    t.string  "email"
    t.integer "content_count"
  end

end
```

I have a for set up in html that sends a post request to the application_controller.rb and this is what it looks like:

HTML:

```
<form action="/login" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
  <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username"/>
  <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
  <!-- <input type="hidden" name="login" value="true"/> -->
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

application_controller.rb

```
post '/signup' do
    @password=params[:password]
    @confirm_password=params[:confirm_password]
    @error=""

    if @password!=@confirm_password
      @error="passwords do not match"
    # elsif username is already taken
      # @error="username already exists"
    else
      @user= User.new({:username => params[:username], :password => params[:password], :email => params[:email]})
    end
    erb :welcome
  end

  post '/login' do
    @username=params[:username]
    @password=params[:password]
    # if user credentials are correct
    erb :index
    # else error message
    erb :login_error
```

How would I make it so that it check that the username matches the password in the Users database.

This is what I found to put in the User class, but I do not know how to use it:

```
  def self.authenticate_safely_simply(user_name, password)
    where(user_name: user_name, password: password).first
  end
```

Secondly how would I make it return the user_id so that I can use it in the next page. I would like to make it so when the user creates new content it adds the user_id to the content the user create in the content table.

I hope I am clear enough. Please let me know if I am not.

Thank you very much.

Comment: have you looked into using devise? http://www.gotealeaf.com/blog/how-to-use-devise-in-rails-for-authentication. It is a well tested authentication gem that also handles signing up and logging in for you. As far as security goes it is safer to use a well tested implementation than to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 0):

Storing plain text passwords is insecure.You can use ActiveModel `has_secure_password` for secure authentication using password. In order to use it you need bcrypt-ruby gem in you Gemfile, and your users table need to have a field called password digest. You can find a complete example gist [here](https://gist.github.com/thebucknerlife/10090014)

.